How to Reference a SQL Server Data Type
The SQL Server TRY_CAST and TRY_CONVERT conversion functions each accept a data_type parameter. I am trying to invoke these functions from the Jakarta Persistence Criteria API. It seems the CriteriaBuilder.function() method is the way to go, but what I'm tripping on is how to pass in the required data_type. For my use case, the data type is determined at runtime, so I can't hard code the value into a native query or query fragment...I need to pass the data type as a parameter somehow.
Here's the first thing I tried...
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...;
Path somePath = ...;
...
cb.function("try_convert", Date.class, cb.literal("DATE"), somePath);

This gets me really close, producing the following SQL:
try_convert('DATE', path.Value)

Unfortunately, that SQL doesn't work. SQL Server throws an exception upon query:
[Incorrect syntax near 'DATE'.]

This matches the results I get when I isolate the conversion clause:
select try_convert('DATE', '1/1/2024').  -- Produces "Incorrect syntax near 'DATE'"
select try_convert(DATE, '1/1/2024').  -- Produces '2024-01-01'

So apparently, the problem is with me passing in text when try_convert expects a data_type. Since DATE (and BIT, and NVARCHAR, etc., etc.) is a reserved word, is there a way to de-reference that data type, either in the Criteria API or in native SQL Server functions?
There are a couple of SQL Server functions that seem like the'd solve my problem, those being TYPE_NAME and TYPE_ID.
For instance, these queries work, and they have the advantage that I can pass in a text parameter:
select type_id('BIT')                 -- Produces 104
select type_name(type_id('BIT'))      -- Produces 'bit'

Since the type_name function advertises that it returns a type of sysname, perhaps its result will make type_convert happy? Unfortunately, no:
select try_convert(type_name(type_id('BIT')), 'true')  -- Produces "Incorrect syntax near '('"
select try_convert(BIT, 'true')                        -- Produces true
select try_convert(BIT, 1)                             -- Produces true

PLEASE NOTE: The column I am performing these conversions on is the sql_variant type (can't be helped) and it contains a variety of value types. I'm able to do simple casting just fine in JPA using Expression.as(), but that fails against this column. The TRY_CONVERT and TRY_CAST functions have a nice feature of "trying" to cast and returning null if they fail.

SQL is statically typed, so no you can't use it dynamically like that. I have no idea whether Criteria can do that for you. But if you need to do it in SQL you need to use dynamic SQL which I will leave you to research.

This may (or may not) help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73950380/6305294

The data type parameter of TRY_CONVERT is part of the syntax so it cannot be parametrized in anyway, you need to use some kind of raw sql with JPA to handle this.
